# R converting XML nodesets of <p> elements into dataframe when scraping table with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

We are pulling contact info from `https://nbpa.com/agents/directory`. There is no table on the page, but rather `<div>s` with `<p>` elements inside:

[image]

We can grab this element with:

```
agents_url <- "https://nbpa.com/agents/directory"
agents_page <- agents_url %>% read_html()
agents_page_elements <- agents_page %>% html_nodes('div.accordion-inner')

agents_page_elements[1]
agents_page_elements[1] %>% html_nodes('p')
```

We are looking to convert this into a 1-row dataframe:

```
Cell             Email                  Professional Credentials:
(123) 456-7890   firstlast@email.com    "NBA Certified Player Agent..."
```

Is this possible to do? The challenging part about this web scrape is that each **accordion-inner** div on the website has **different p elements**. Some have Cell: and Email:, others have Education:, Address:, etc. It varies by accordion-inner. If we can turn each individual node into a 1-row dataframe, we can then rbind all dataframes together using `plyr::rbind.fill()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `read.dcf` after getting as `text`

```
new <- agents_page_elements[1] %>%
     html_nodes('p') %>%
     html_text()
as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(new)))
```

-output

```
    Cell                            Email                                                             Professional Credentials
1 (240) 668-4241 barry.aberdeen@tributesports.com NBA Certified Player Agent, FIBA Certified Player Agent, WNBA Certified Player Agent
```

---

For multiple elements, use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
out <- map_dfr(agents_page_elements, ~ {
       new <- .x %>% 
               html_nodes('p') %>%
               html_text() %>%
               str_replace_all("\n\\s*", " ")
    if(length(new) > 0) {
       as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(new)))
     } else NULL

     })
```

-output

```
> dim(out)
[1] 455   9
> head(out, 2)
            Cell                            Email                                                             Professional Credentials    Title
1 (240) 668-4241 barry.aberdeen@tributesports.com NBA Certified Player Agent, FIBA Certified Player Agent, WNBA Certified Player Agent     <NA>
2 (281) 773-7339                             <NA>                                     Texas Bar No. 24050197|Wisconsin Bar No. 1045470 Attorney
             Company Name                                                                                             Education Address Office International
1                    <NA>                                                                                                  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>          <NA>
2 Adams & Associates, LLC University of Southern California B.S. |University of Houston - M.B.A |University of Wisconsin - J.D.    <NA>   <NA>          <NA>
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. do you think it is possible to grab the names as well? I am trying to update this solution to also grab names. They are located in sibling <a> elements which makes grabbing the names a bit tough

Comment: @Canovice if you know the location.  Within the `map`, you can construct another call, and cbind with the  data.frame created with `new'

Comment: Yep i did something like that and got the names. thanks

Comment: My mind is officially a bit blown by this. + R just keeps surprising me. Thanks for this.

Comment: I went away to try and better understand how this "magic" works. Does there need to be a close on the textConnection and an unlink associated with read.dcf or is this handled because you never assign the immediate return of these to variables?

Comment: @QHarr In `R`, you don't need to explicitly specify the `return`.  it would return the value of the last evaluated expression.  i..e `map` is kind of a `lapply` - `lapply(1:5, function(x) data.frame(col1 = x))`

Comment: Thank you. What happens with the connection object you create? The documentation says call `close` on it. Likewise, read.dcf specifies unlink to remove the file. I'm trying to understand why in your code neither of these need to be specified? Is there "out-of-scope garbage collection"? Sorry, trying to frame how R works in terms of other languages I am familiar with - possibly a bad idea!

Comment: @QHarr i don't generally use `close` with `read.table(textConnection(..` etc.  But, as you said, it may be better to close