# How to break Char Vectors up at defined terms?

Tags: web-scraping, split, strsplit

I am scraping data off a website using rvest() for the first time.

It gave me a character vector that I am trying to split and convert to a data frame with columns.

How do you turn this vector:

char.vector <- c("John DoeTeacherSpeaksEnglishJapaneseRateUSD 10Video Intro","JaneTutorSpeaksJapaneseFrenchRateUSD 15Video Intro")

...into this data frame with columns:

| Name | Role | English | Japanese | French | Rate_USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | Teacher | 1 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| Jane | Tutor | 0 | 1 | 1 | 15 |

Splitting on spaces or character position is problematic. Is there maybe a way to create a vector of all the words I want to split at and use it as the split argument?

split.vector <- c("Teacher", "Tutor", "Speaks", "English", "Japanese", "French", "Rate", "Video")

My code and url:

```r
EN.char <- read_html("https://www.italki.com/teachers/english") %>%
             html_nodes(".teacher-card") %>%
             html_text()

EN.char
```

Comment: Can you share your code and html/url?

Comment: @QHarr Question updated with url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as there are potentially different numbers of languages for each entry, I shamelessly took the approach used by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) in their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278648), whereby `read.dcf` is used to map out all the languages present, and put NA where a language is not present for a given entry. After having read [this](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/dcf.html) article I saw that:

> The DCF rules as implemented in R are:
>
> 1. A database consists of one or more records, each with one or more
>    named fields. Not every record must contain each field, a field may
>    appear only once in a record.
> 2. Regular lines start with a non-whitespace character.
> 3. Regular lines are of form tag:value, i.e.,
>    have a name tag and a value for the field, separated by : (only the
>    first : counts). The value can be empty (=whitespace only).
> 4. Lines starting with whitespace are continuation lines (to the preceding
>    field) if at least one character in the line is non-whitespace.
> 5. Records are separated by one or more empty (=whitespace only) lines.

In order to resolve a malformed line error, I needed to fix rule 3 and insert ":" so as to have tag:value pairs.

Following @akrun's example, I wrapped the `read.dcf` within an `as.data.frame` call. I kept the unnecessary, in this case, `if` statement, for safety of missing entries. I doubt languages would be missing given the nature of the site.

I then used `replace_na()` to switch out NA with "0" and cast all the language columns as integer.

I then generated another DataFrame, with all the other details required, which only had one entry per field in the record (row). As I was sure of matching, and ordered, rows, I then used `cbind()` to join the DataFrames column-wise.

N.B. Given my location, the USD values are actually showing as GBP.

---

**R:**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://www.italki.com/teachers/english")
entries <- page %>% html_elements(".teacher-card")

language_df <- map_dfr(entries, ~ {
  new <- .x %>%
    html_elements("p + div > div") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    paste0(., ":1")
  if (length(new) > 0) {
    as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(new)))
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), ~ as.integer(tidyr::replace_na(.x, 0))))

details_df <- map_dfr(entries, ~
data.frame(
  name = .x %>% html_element("div > .overflow-hidden") %>% html_text(),
  role = .x %>% html_element("span + div > .text-tiny") %>% html_text(),
  rate_usd = .x %>% html_element(".flex-1:nth-child(1) > div > span") %>% html_text()
))

results <- cbind(details_df, language_df)
```

---

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @QHarr, could you give one more time a check whether [this one](https://filebin.varnish-software.com/yx05zobrycqsv5hc/script.txt) works? Sorry for any inconvenience.