# CSS Selector found with rvest and not with RSelenium

Tags: css, r, rvest, rselenium

The goal is to read the 1-5yr GIC rates for Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term and Compound Interest under the Non-Cashable GICs tab.

Selector Gadget tells me that the css identifier is `#container-9565195e5e .cmp-chart__chart span`. Using `rvest`:

```
page <- read_html('https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/saving-investing/gic-rates-canada/')
page %>% 
  html_nodes("#container-9565195e5e .cmp-chart__chart span") 

# {xml_nodeset (5)}
# [1] <span data-source="tdct-gic" data-view="single" data-filter-item="productId:315|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:1" data-value="postedRate"></span>
#   [2] <span data-source="tdct-gic" data-view="single" data-filter-item="productId:315|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:2" data-value="postedRate"></span>
#   [3] <span data-source="tdct-gic" data-view="single" data-filter-item="productId:315|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:3" data-value="postedRate"></span>
#   [4] <span data-source="tdct-gic" data-view="single" data-filter-item="productId:315|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:4" data-value="postedRate"></span>
#   [5] <span data-source="tdct-gic" data-view="single" data-filter-item="productId:315|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:5" data-value="postedRate"></span>}
```

rvest can't read the actual rates because of the use of JavaScript on the site.

Turning to `RSelenium` using the same css selector results in an error:

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/saving-investing/gic-rates-canada/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "#container-9565195e5e .cmp-chart__chart span")

# Selenium message:Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#container-9565195e5e .cmp-chart__chart span"}
# For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
# Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
# System info: host: 'ef4080d2cb73', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-135-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
# Driver info: driver.version: unknown
# 
# Error:     Summary: NoSuchElement
# Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
# class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
# Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

So how do I use RSelenium to read the 1-5yr rates for *Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term and Compound Interest* for *Non-registered and Registered (TFSA, RSP, RIF, RESP)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced RSelenium with [Chromote](https://rstudio.github.io/chromote/) (which is on its way to rvest: [r4ds](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/webscraping.html#dynamic-sites), [gh](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/245)). The selector in question seems to refer to another table, *Long-Term and **Simple** Interest*. While values are currently the same, still switched to the one mentioned in question.

```r
library(chromote)
library(rvest)
b <- ChromoteSession$new()
# Display the current session in the Chromote browser:
# b$view()

b$Page$navigate("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/saving-investing/gic-rates-canada/")
b$Page$loadEventFired()

# Non-Cashable GICs >> Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term and Compound Interest
b$Runtime$evaluate("document.querySelector('#container-8a263227af table').outerHTML")$result$value %>% 
  minimal_html() %>% 
  html_element("table") %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   Term    `Non-registered and Registered (TFSA, RSP, RIF, RESP)`
#>   <chr>   <chr>                                                 
#> 1 1 year  4.65%                                                 
#> 2 2 years 4.35%                                                 
#> 3 3 years 3.75%                                                 
#> 4 4 years 4%                                                    
#> 5 5 years 4.05%
```

```r
### Few alternatives
# evalute js in runtime: 
sapply(1:5, \(x) b$Runtime$evaluate(paste0("document.querySelector('[data-filter-item=\"productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:",x,"\"]').innerText"))$result$value)
#> [1] "4.65" "4.35" "3.75" "4"    "4.05"

doc <- b$DOM$getDocument()
# elements where "data-filter-item" attribute starts with "productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:"
nodeids <- b$DOM$querySelectorAll(doc$root$nodeId, '[data-filter-item^="productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:"]')
sapply(nodeids$nodeIds, \(x) b$DOM$getOuterHTML(x) %>% minimal_html() %>% html_text())
#> [1] "4.65" "4.35" "3.75" "4"    "4.05"

# close session
b$close()
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The page does an initial POST request that gets all the data (let's call it *master*) for all the options. It then uses the various data-filter-item attribute values associated with a given table's cells e.g., `data-filter-item="productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:1"`, to filter the master data to the items needed to update that table.

You can replicate a simplified version of this POST request, create a DataFrame of all values in the `value` part of the response (think of it like a master reference table), then extract the required filters from a request to the original URI

```
> filters
[1] "productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:1" "productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:2"
[3] "productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:3" "productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:4"
[5] "productId:703|minimumDepositAmt:0.01|minimumTermYearCnt:5"
```

and turn those into a DataFrame for filtering.

You can then subset the master table using the smaller DataFrame. Column names will be matched upon if set in the master using the key values from the key:value response.

Finally, update the table, when extracted from request response for initial webpage, by updating the relevant column with the rate % from the filtered master DataFrame.

The html from the initial webpage is invalid so the target table selection was not as straightforward as I would like.

The CSS selector list I went with was designed with hopefully a longer shelf-life, in terms of remaining valid for longer than a more brittle path might.

One other thing to show might be the response from the POST request. The response has the following key:value format, where I use the key column to generate headers for my master DataFrame. The values get turned into the master DataFrame of all possible rates (and other dynamic page info.)

[image]

---

Credit:

I took the approach used by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) in their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278648), whereby read.dcf is used to map out a set of rows, with potentially repeated/new headers, into a single DataFrame with all headers present. NA is entered if a particular entry is not present in a given processed row.

This allowed me to turn this list of split filtering instructions:

```
> lapply(filters, str_split, "\\|") %>% unlist(recursive = F)
[[1]]
[1] "productId:703"          "minimumDepositAmt:0.01" "minimumTermYearCnt:1"  

[[2]]
[1] "productId:703"          "minimumDepositAmt:0.01" "minimumTermYearCnt:2"  

[[3]]
[1] "productId:703"          "minimumDepositAmt:0.01" "minimumTermYearCnt:3"  

[[4]]
[1] "productId:703"          "minimumDepositAmt:0.01" "minimumTermYearCnt:4"  

[[5]]
[1] "productId:703"          "minimumDepositAmt:0.01" "minimumTermYearCnt:5"
```

into this:

```
> data_df
  productId minimumDepositAmt minimumTermYearCnt
1       703              0.01                  1
2       703              0.01                  2
3       703              0.01                  3
4       703              0.01                  4
5       703              0.01                  5
```

i.e. the set of filtering instructions for the master DataFrame as a DataFrame

The master DataFrame looking as follows:

```
> df %>% head()

  productId minimumDepositAmt maximumDepositAmt minimumTermYearCnt maximumTermYearCnt minimumTermDayCnt maximumTermDayCnt postedRate
1       107              0.01           4999.99                  0                  0                90               119          4
2       107              5000           9999.99                  0                  0                90               119          4
3       107             10000          24999.99                  0                  0                90               119          4
4       107             25000          49999.99                  0                  0                90               119          4
5       107             50000          99999.99                  0                  0                90               119          4
6       107            100000         249999.99                  0                  0                90               119          4
  minimumMarketGrowthRate maximumMarketGrowthRate stepperYear1Rate stepperYear2Rate stepperYear3Rate stepperYear4Rate stepperYear5Rate
1                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
2                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
3                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
4                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
5                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
6                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
```

The subset master DataFrame:

```
> filtered_df
  productId minimumDepositAmt minimumTermYearCnt maximumDepositAmt maximumTermYearCnt minimumTermDayCnt maximumTermDayCnt postedRate
1       703              0.01                  1           4999.99                  1                 0               364       4.65
2       703              0.01                  2           4999.99                  2                 0               364       4.35
3       703              0.01                  3           4999.99                  3                 0               364       3.75
4       703              0.01                  4           4999.99                  4                 0               364          4
5       703              0.01                  5           4999.99                  5                 0               364       4.05
  minimumMarketGrowthRate maximumMarketGrowthRate stepperYear1Rate stepperYear2Rate stepperYear3Rate stepperYear4Rate stepperYear5Rate
1                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
2                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
3                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
4                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
5                       0                       0                0                0                0                0                0
```

The extracted table, from initial page, before update:

```
> table
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  Term    `Non-registered and Registered (TFSA, RSP, RIF, RESP)`
  <chr>   <chr>                                                 
1 1 year  %                                                     
2 2 years %                                                     
3 3 years %                                                     
4 4 years %                                                     
5 5 years %
```

And the table after update using master (df - data from POST request to get rates info):

```
> print(table)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  Term    `Non-registered and Registered (TFSA, RSP, RIF, RESP)`
  <chr>   <chr>                                                 
1 1 year  4.65%                                                 
2 2 years 4.35%                                                 
3 3 years 3.75%                                                 
4 4 years 4%                                                    
5 5 years 4.05%
```

---

r:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

page <- read_html("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/personal-investing/products/gic/gic-rates-canada")
table_node <- page %>%
  html_element('div.container:contains("Guaranteed Investment Certificate - Long-Term") .text:contains("Compound") ~ div table')

filters <- table_node %>%
  html_elements("[data-filter-item]") %>%
  html_attr("data-filter-item")

res <- request("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/getRates/") %>%
  req_headers(
    "user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0", 
    "content-type" = "application/json",
    "x-kl-ajax-request" = "Ajax_Request"
  ) %>%
  req_body_json(list("errorText" = "Unable to get the rate", "ratesType" = "gic")) %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_string()

data <- jsonlite::parse_json(res, simplifyVector = T)

df <- set_names(data$value %>% as.data.frame(), data$key)

data_df <- map_dfr(lapply(filters, str_split, "\\|") %>%
  unlist(recursive = F), ~ {
  new <-
    if (length(.x) > 0) {
      as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(.x)))
    } else {
      NULL
    }
})

filtered_df <- inner_join(data_df, df)

table <- table_node %>% html_table()

table[2] <- str_c(filtered_df$postedRate, table[[2]])

print(table)
```